# gmaps4rails disable scroll wheel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails like so:

```
  <%= gmaps("map_options" => { "scrollwheel" => false, "zoom" => 17, "auto_zoom" => false },"markers" => { "data" => event.to_gmaps4rails }) %>
```

This is generating:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsGoogle();
Gmaps.load_map = function() {
Gmaps.map.map_options.scrollwheel = false;
Gmaps.map.map_options.zoom = 17;
Gmaps.map.map_options.auto_zoom = false;
Gmaps.map.initialize();
Gmaps.map.markers = [{"lat":38.6419,"lng":-90.2646}];
Gmaps.map.create_markers();
Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
Gmaps.map.callback();
};
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong that is ignoring the `scrollwheel = false` option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Historically", I added in the map options some features from the providers. This was a bad idea since I didn't extract everything and I started to receive some pull requests for the rest of it...

Too much code for very low added value.

In your case, `scrollwheel` isn't included in the list [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/%28Multiple%29-Maps). So the best options is to use the `raw` key (also described in the link above).

This would lead you to the following code:

```
  <%= gmaps("map_options" => { :raw => "{scrollwheel: false}", "zoom" => 17, "auto_zoom" => false },"markers" => { "data" => event.to_gmaps4rails }) %>
```