# gmaps4rails disabling zoom

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to disable scroll when I build my map, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
:javascript
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { map_options: { scrollwheel: false, zoomControl:   false }, markers: { maxRandomDistance: null }, builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });
  handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'geolocation'} }, function(){
...
});
```

Comment: Because we did it in a JS tag we couldn't use the erb solutions, this worked for us:

    handler.getMap().setOptions({ scrollwheel: false })

Comment: As the gem author, I'd advise you too do it in the constructor as instructed in my answer

Answer (score 5):

According [to the doc](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails), you can change global settings when you create the handler.

You can change object options in the build function.

So do:

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null }, builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });

handler.buildMap({ provider: { scrollwheel: false, zoomControl: false }, internal: {id: 'geolocation'} }, function(){
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567014/gmaps4rails-disable-scroll-wheel)

```
  <%= gmaps("map_options" => { :raw => "{scrollwheel: false}", "zoom" => 17, "auto_zoom" => false },"markers" => { "data" => event.to_gmaps4rails }) %>
```

[This might help too..](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/%28Multiple%29-Maps)